# Remove element completely from div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got multiple svg with a common class.

```
<div id="holder">
   <svg width="100" height="100" class="circle">
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   </svg>
</div>
```

How can I remove it completely? I tried `.empty();` and `remove();` but did not work?

```
$('#removeBtn').click(function(){
    $('.circle').remove();
});
```

Comment: is this `removeBtn` a class or id ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny - no, `.circle` was correct

Comment: @Bekki - your code works as is

Comment: @ArunPJohny: JaromandaX is correct. I want to remove the SVG.

Comment: Is your code inside a DOM ready handler? (or at least after the elements it references)? (i.e. the `removeBtn` button)

Comment: @Bekki Yes.. missed that - it is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/umnugruq/1/

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: spot on... thanks.

Comment: are you sure your button click handler is getting called

Comment: In case you missed it, I added my comment as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you missed a DOM ready handler :)

e.g.

```
$(function(){
    $('#removeBtn').click(function(){
        $('.circle').remove();
    });
});
```

`$(function(){})` is just a handy shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Answer (score -1):

your html

```
   <div id="holder">
       <svg width="100" height="100" class="circle">
         <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
       </svg>
    </div>

<button id="removeBtn" >remove</button>
```

and js

```
$('#removeBtn').click(function(){

    $('.circle').remove()
});
```

here the fiddle

[https://jsfiddle.net/ptosn8w6/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/ptosn8w6/2/)